# Calculate the mean germination per species per week

Tags: r, mean

I got a dataset where I recorded the germination of seeds from different species (Species) in different soil types (Soil_origin) weekly. I got four replicas for each species, in other words: for each species x soil type I had four containers with in each containing ten seeds. I would like to calculate the average germination for each week for each species x soil type (thus the average of n=4).

I do not know how to include my dataset in this script...

I hope you can help me out with this!

Thank you for your time.

```
### My dataset is too large, therefore here I only included the first 10 rows...


> dput(head(Data_bakken_R, 10))
structure(list(Soil_origin = c("P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", 
"P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c", "P_c"), Species = c("C_flava", "C_flava", 
"C_flava", "C_flava", "C_flacca", "C_flacca", "C_flacca", "C_flacca", 
"C_panicea", "C_panicea"), Pot = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2), Date = structure(c(1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 
1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000, 1685664000
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Day_since_cooling = c(6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), Total_start = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10), Germinated = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

### Install packages 
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)

install.packages('tidyverse')
library(tidyverse)

### Plot per soil type
Data_bakken_R %>% 
  mutate(Proportion_germination = Germinated/Total_start) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Day_since_cooling, y = Proportion_germination, color = Soil_origin)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(Species)) +
  labs(x = "Time (days)", y = "Proportion of germinated seeds") + theme_classic() + ylim (0.0, 1.0)  `
```

Comment: Hi Stefanie.  You can use `dput(Data_bakken_R)` in R to get a version of your dataset that you can post here.  It would also help if you explain what the problem is and what output you would like from your script.

Comment: My dataset is too long, therefore I included the first 10 rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably use `grup_by()` together with `week()`:

```
Data_bakken_R %>% 
  mutate(weeknum = week(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Soil_origin, Species, Day_since_cooling, weeknum) %>% 
  summarise(Proportion_germination = sum(Germinated)/sum(Total_start)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Day_since_cooling, y = Proportion_germination, color = Soil_origin)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(Species)) +
  labs(x = "Time (days)", y = "Proportion of germinated seeds") + theme_classic() + ylim (0.0, 1.0)
```

However I don't know what to do with `Day_since_cooling` as you haven't mentioned it in your question. That's why I added this variable to grouping as well.

Comment: I get the follow output: Error in Data_bakken_R %>% mutate(weeknum = week(Date)) %>% group_by(Soil_origin,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: @StefanievandenBerg you need to call `library(tidyverse)` as it was stated in your question

Comment: This worked out great, thank you so much for your help!